# What is the first version/build of mobile Safari that supports access to the GPS fix?

Tags: android, iphone, geolocation, version, mobile-safari

**What's the first version/build of mobile Safari (on Droid & iPhone) which supports accessing the GPS fix by GeoLocation API?**

I need to know exactly where the version break is - since elder version obviously do not support GPS fix, only WiFi estimation.

The ideal and for sure accepted answer would be user-agent strings of 2 consequent builds (of which one supports it while the other doesn't).

This is a re-post of a closed question, refined to match nicely into the Q&A scheme, hopefully.

Please do not post any hyperlinks to the W3C specs or similar Google top-hits for these keywords...

Merely the Safari & AppleWebKit tags are relevant - which have the build numbers.

This question is barely browser version/build related - built-in hardware GPS support is assumed -

It is also assumed, that GeoLocation API is enabled and that the user confirms the request.

Comment: Background: My tests on Android 2.2 with mobile Safari 4.0 (build 533.1) dearly failed, but succeeded on Fennec 8.0 (on the very same device). Another user reported it worked for him on mobile Safari (don't know which OS/browser version). This leads to the conclusion that elder versions do not support access to the GPS fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sound as if you just the answer you want to hear.

The actual answer is it's not that simple. You are making certain assumptions regarding hardware that aren't true.

Let's take the iPad for example. A second generation WiFi iPad and a 3G iPad **have the same user agent**. But only the 3G iPad has GPS. It's not the browser version that determines GPS, it's the hardware you're running on.

Furthermore, just because your device *has* GPS is no guarantee it will be used or available.

The 'ideal' answer that you're looking for simply doesn't exist: and even if it did, there would be thousands upon thousands of user agents you'd need, because it's dependent on many factors, including hardware and OS version.

Comment: I mean, that particular user-agent string of the example you've stated should be considered a version which does support access to the GPS fix - since it's most likely the same version of mobile Safari installed to both of them; lack of hardware-support is another story.